# .formValidation is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, validation

**Original Issue:**

My form is hitting the validation correctly but submitting when it shouldn't be.

Following http://formvalidation.io/examples/ajax-submit/

Viewing my console I don't see any of the log statements in the `.on` "error" section or the "success" printed out. And the page just posts to itself. With the data in the url. I don't know what I'm missing here as basically it skips all `.on` statements.

What is going on here?

Remember Validation works just non of the `.on` statements.

HTML:

```
<form id="service_path_form" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Service Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="service_path_name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">IP</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="service_path_ip" placeholder="IP" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Description</label>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="service_path_description" rows="3" placeholder="Write a short Description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Enable</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="service_path_enabled" value="1" /> Enabled
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="service_path_enabled" value="0" /> Disabled
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="validate" value="Validate and Submit">Validate and Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="created_by" value="{{request.user}}">
<input type="hidden" name="date_created" id = "date_created" value="">
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#service_path_form')
      .bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            service_path_name: {
                // The messages for this field are shown as usual
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Service Path Name is required'
                    },
                }
            },
            service_path_ip: {
                // Show the message in a tooltip
                err: 'tooltip',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The destination ip address is required'
                    },
                    ip: {
                        message: 'The ip address is not valid'
                    }
                }
            },
            service_path_enabled: {
                // Show the message in a tooltip
                err: 'tooltip',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Do you want this service path to be actively monitored?'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('err.form.fv', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e)
      console.log('test')
    })
    .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
      // Prevent form submission
      console.log("MADE IT HERE")
      e.preventDefault();

      var $form = $(e.target),
          fv    = $form.data('formValidation');

      // Use Ajax to submit form data
      console.log("MADE IT HERE")
      $.ajax({
          url: "/servicepathapi/v1/servicepaths/",
          type: 'POST',
          data: $form.serialize(),
          success: function(result) {
              console.log(result)
          }
      });
  })
});
</script>
```

**CURRENT:**

Update with suggested upgrade:

I tried @Arkni 's suggestion, while I feel like it's in the right direction with I'm now getting this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'app/scripts/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js' %}" ></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'form_validation/js/formValidation.js' %}" ></script>
<script src="{% static 'form_validation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js' %}" ></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#service_path_form')
      .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
```

With this output:

[image: Screen shot of js console]

**FIX:**
While checking all of my source files I noticed that I was actually loading jquery 2.0.2 and 2.1.3, removing 2.0.2 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using FormValidation, you should try to remove jquery.validate.min.js as I am afraid of the confliction.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nghuuphuoc/8o7rhykf/) works properly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/formvalidation/css/formValidation.min.css">

<form id="service_path_form" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Service Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="service_path_name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">IP</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="service_path_ip" placeholder="IP" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Description</label>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="service_path_description" rows="3" placeholder="Write a short Description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Enable</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="service_path_enabled" value="1" /> Enabled
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="service_path_enabled" value="0" /> Disabled
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="validate" value="Validate and Submit">Validate and Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The scripts:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#service_path_form')
  .formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        service_path_name: {
            // The messages for this field are shown as usual
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The Service Path Name is required'
                },
            }
        },
        service_path_ip: {
            // Show the message in a tooltip
            err: 'tooltip',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The destination ip address is required'
                },
                ip: {
                    message: 'The ip address is not valid'
                }
            }
        },
        service_path_enabled: {
            // Show the message in a tooltip
            err: 'tooltip',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Do you want this service path to be actively monitored?'
                }
            }
        }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is the result showing how it looks like:

[image: Result]

I hope it helps you.

Comment: In fact, there is no confliction between FormValidation and Jquery-Validation, they use different namespaces. he found a conflict between 2 version of JQuery.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hu76tkhv/ whats wrong with this i have added  login form  code and used cdn which is used for above question @Phuoc Nguyen

Comment: your answer should work all kind of form not the particular question

Comment: i see that when any code put to your fiddle its working but.. Same CDN copy to new fiddle put some other code its working

Answer (score 5):

As you said in your question, you are using [FormValidation](http://formvalidation.io/) not [BootstrapValidator](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/).

So to solve your problem, replace this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#service_path_form')
        .bootstrapValidator({ // <====
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#service_path_form')
        .formValidation({ // <====
```

---

Some notes:

- [FormValidation](http://formvalidation.io/news/v0.6.0-released/) is the new name of [BootstrapValidator](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/) from version 0.6.0.
- BootstrapValidator is deprecated and not supported anymore.
- See [this guide](http://formvalidation.io/news/upgrading-to-v0.6.0/) to upgrade from BootstrapValidator to Formvalidation.

Comment: I've added a bit more... Thanks!